"Your speakers aren't working", but they are
I have this strange problem where Teams says it can't output audio in calls (microphone works fine), while any other application in the system can output audio perfectly
During the call I try to go to Audio Settings and reselect or turn off and on the correct audio device, but doesn't change anything. I've tried restarting Teams and Windows
I've searched for this error message and there are some results about it but none of them really address this specific problem, they all talk about the case where audio doesn't work system-wide
It's Windows 11, NEW Microsoft Teams
ASUS ExpertBook laptop, Realtek Audio
This is the error itself:

The settings inside Microsoft Teams, which show that the correct device is selected (the laptop integrated speakers, "Altavoces" in Spanish):

And the Windows settings, which show that the device (the laptop integrated speakers, "Altavoces" in Spanish) is detected (which is expected, because any other Windows program can output audio), that it is selected by default, and that it's the same device selected in Teams:


Post the Device Settings. This error essentially suggests you don’t have speakers or the default device isn’t configured

Can you show Setting-Sound be sure to provide an English translation.

both details added

Teams doesn't support all devices. Try to install VoiceMeeter to act as bridge to the device, per this link.

It seems to be a faulty Realtek driver update, now another Realtek update appeared and it's working
